# vb with mysql connection on login

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Trying to connect two table with one login page but when i run it, only the adminpage opens while the agentpage does not (gives me a login not successful)

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class Admin_Login
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
    Dim query As String


    Private Sub OK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOk.Click

        conn = New MySqlConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user id=root;password=samlock124;database=imsdb"
        Dim dr As MySqlDataReader

        Try


            If txtusername.Text.Length = 7 And txtpassword.Text.Length = 7 Then
                conn.Open()
                Dim query As String
                query = String.Format("select * from imsdb.agentlogintb where username = '{0}' AND password = '{1}'", Me.txtusername.Text.Trim(), Me.txtpassword.Text.Trim())
                cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                agentpage.Show()
                Me.Hide()

            Else
                MsgBox("login not succesful")

            End If




            If txtusername.Text.Length > 7 And txtpassword.Text.Length > 7 Then
                conn.Open()
                Dim query As String
                query = String.Format("select * from adminlogintb where username = '{0}' AND password = '{1}'", Me.txtusername.Text.Trim(), Me.txtpassword.Text.Trim())
                cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                Admin_Form.Show()
                Me.Hide()

            Else
                MsgBox("login not succesful")

            End If


            conn.Close()

        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Finally
            conn.Dispose()

        End Try
    End Sub


    Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btncancel.Click
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub
```

Comment: use SQL parameters rather than concatenating or formatting strings.  What you have will crash on `Charles D'Artagnan` or `Billy O'Toole`.  ALso never ever store passwords as plain text - hash and salt them

Comment: If the admin shows then it gets to the second part isnt the connection already open? you're calling `conn.Open()` again... maybe this is part of your problem.

Comment: Of course your two conditions cannot be true at the same time.  _If txtusername.Text.Length = 7 And txtpassword.Text.Length = 7 Then_ and  _If txtusername.Text.Length > 7 And txtpassword.Text.Length > 7 Then_ only one will be true

Comment: ...and `Admin_Form.Show()` looks like default form instances